# SpringBootTest in error with h2 v2.1.214 because of PageRequest

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I have some tests in error after upgrading from Spring boot 2.5.6 to 2.7.3.

For information we use Oracle for the database and h2 for tests.

I have some tests in failure with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException
```

In fact, the version of h2 was 1.4.200 before and is 2.1.214 now and a lot of things seem to have changed. The reason of the error is not always the same according to the test in error. Sometimes it is an error with a table not found (not solved yet), sometimes it is an error with "Values of types "BOOLEAN" and "INTEGER" are not comparable" (solved by updating a query where a comparison was done with a boolean column like this `myBoolean = 0` and it has been updated to `myBoolean = false`) and I also have an error on a query done with a PageRequest.

For this last case, I have a Controller like this:

```
public Page<MyEntity> doSomething() {
    final Sort sort = Sort.by(Order.desc("column1"));
    final PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, 1000, sort);
    return myEntityRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
}
```

But I have an error like that:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "select myentity0_.id as id1_47_, myentity0_.column1 as column1_47_, myentity0_.column2 as column2_47_ from my_table myentity0_ order by myentity0_.column1 desc [*]limit ?"; SQL statement:
select myentity0_.id as id1_47_, myentity0_.column1 as column1_47_, myentity0_.column2 as column2_47_ from my_table myentity0_ order by myentity0_.column1 desc limit ? [42000-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:247)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:898)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:572)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
    ... 205 more
```

If I change the Controller like this,the test is in success:

```
public Page<MyEntity> doSomething() {
    List<MyEntity> result = myEntityRepository.findAll();
    return new PageImpl<MyEntity>(result);
}
```

So It seems that the problem was due by the use of PageRequest.

Do you have an idea please?

Comment: H2 1.4 to 2.0 is a breaking change and needs modifications to your configuration to work.

Comment: Have you considered to create a more realistic (oracle) test instance? Makes your tests "more realistic" and this problem vanish ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java persistence libraries are usually tested only with default Regular mode of H2 and may not work well with other modes.

Oracle doesn't support MySQL/PostgreSQL-style `LIMIT`, and H2 doesn't allow it in Oracle compatibility mode, but some libraries produce `LIMIT` instead of standard `OFFSET` / `FETCH` for H2.

Spring Data JDBC (spring-data-relational) added support of custom compatibility modes of H2 only about a month ago and version 2.4.3 with this fix isn't released yet.

Hibernate ORM 6.*.* should work well, but Hibernate ORM 5.6.* has a known issue:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/issues/HHH-15318

You can enable `LIMIT` in Oracle compatibility mode of H2 as a temporary workaround. To do that, you need to execute the following Java code during initialization of your application:

```java
org.h2.engine.Mode mode = org.h2.engine.Mode.getInstance("ORACLE");
mode.limit = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know why everything worked with previous version of h2 (1.4.200) and why with version 2.1.214 everything is broken? For information, I have something like this in the application.yml for tests "jdbc:h2:mem:my-rest;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=Oracle" (for spring.datasource.url). So yes the Oracle compatibility mode is used so I do not understand why everything is not working like before.

Comment: Because historic versions of H2 were less restrictive and they allowed invalid SQL in many cases. In new versions vendor-specific features are usually restricted to related compatibility modes.

Comment: And do you know why, in Oracle compatibility mode, we have LIMIT in generated SQL instead of OFFSET? Because for Oracle (in production environment) it should be OFFSET when the request is done no?

Comment: Because when you use H2, you also need to use `H2Dialect` even if you use some compatibility mode of H2, you cannot use and shouldn't try to use dialects like `OracleDialect` or others. But `H2Dialect` in old versions of Hibernate ORM and some other libraries produces `LIMIT`, H2 1.3.176 released in 2014 and older versions, unlike modern versions, use that clause instead of standard one.